# How do I increase the voltage of a circuit that powers and transmits data to an led

Tags: arduino, voltage, transistors

I am a noob, but I managed to make a TV-B-Gone out of an Arduino UNO and some parts (I used this tutorial: http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-TV-B-Gone/). It only does one led, but I want it to do more than one. How can I increase the voltage without compromising the integrity of the data in the circuit so i can do more than one?

A note: I know that it has some thing to do with transistors, but the method of doing this doesn't seem to be popular.

Another note: that the schematic didn't work on the page above.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Can you try to ask a more specific question? You want to "increase the voltage" of what? Why don't you think that using transistors is "popular"? In what way didn't the schematic work? Please tell us exactly what you tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 2):

To power more LEDs usually requires more current, not more voltage.

The ATMega328 microcontroller in a typical Arduino has IO pins which can provide enough current to illuminate an indicator LED - say 20 mA. The total current is about 100 mA.

To drive more LEDs or higher powered LEDs you can use a transistor to switch current from the Arduino supply of from a separate supply for the LEDS.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYXOAP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

D1 is a LED directly driven by the Arduino - this must be a low current LED and you can't drive many of them directly.

D2 takes it's power from the supply, not from the Arduino IO pins. The IO pin just supplies a small amount of current to turn on the transistor.

D3 is an example where a high-power LED is provided with a separate power supply. This might be a higher voltage supply - e.g. 12 V instead of the Arduino's 5V supply.

As user33855 commented, this example uses Bipolar Junction Transistors (BJTs) which need a resistor to limit base current. In place of Q1 and Q2 you can instead use MOSFETs which don't need R3 and R5.

You wouldn't normally have a mixture as shown, it's simply an illustration of various options.